# Apply amount on different row using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

[image]

This is the table of customer history and these are sales activities, now customer made a payment of $ 200, which apply on the following ID

5 - Balance After Apply = 0

7 - Balance After Apply = 0

8 - Balance After Apply = 0

10 - Balance After Apply = 85.9

How we can do in hibernate that it get all row (only rows in which balance apply) update accordingly  ?

Comment: Can you clarify? As in write as: "I want to update all rows with this value at that column that are this condition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question but you can try something that looks like:

```
public void updateBalance(float newBalance,List<String> ids) {
    String hql = "update UserHistory set balance= :newBalance where id in (:ids)";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setFloat("newBalance",newBalance);
    query.setParameterList("ids",ids);
    int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowCount);
}

updateBalance(0,Arrays.asList("5","7","8"));
updateBalance(85.9,Arrays.asList("10"));
```

This works fine if you have to set the same balance on multiple rows.

If each row gets potentially a new balance, then you can get the rows using the Criteria API using something like that:

```
Restrictions.in("id", Arrays.asList("5","7","8","10"));
```

and once you have your entities, you can simply update their balance and save them.

Comment: And remember the IN clause of a database may have a limit (1000 on oracle I think)

Comment: well! But I want this automatically. As I enter amount $200, then hibernate automatically take decision of above ;) instead of manually `updateBalance(0,Arrays.asList("5","7","8"));
updateBalance(85.9,Arrays.asList("10"));` this is actually my problem :)

Comment: I don't see how could Hibernate take such a decision, because actually, looking at your db rows, I don't understand myself what your updates try to do. Can this update be expressed as a single SQL request? If it's not the case I don't think Hibernate will handle this for you.

Comment: Ok I took another look and I understand now, and Hibernate can't do this for you, this is applicative logic. You could eventually call a custom stored procedure from hibernate that does this for you but I think you should definitively fetch all the rows, update them and save them until all the money has been spent

Comment: Thanks you got my point. ok ok I understand ! please, if you add some extra code fetch all the rows in hibernate that sum = $ 200. `in My case 4 rows` and `I THINK , THIS IS POSSIBLE` `;)`   **EDITED:** `TOP ROWS`

Comment: I am awaiting of your response... `get all rows in hibernate whose sum is equal to 200` :)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor this is no more an Hibernate question but an SQL question then. You may be able to do this in some databases and may be not with others. I don't think this will be standard SQL by the way, and Hibernate won't help you. If the number of rows is reasonable you'd rather fetch them all, else use pagination to limit memory consumption.

Comment: ok ! but using HQL(like SQL ) in hibernate ! is it not possible ?

Comment: it is possible to call native sql with Hibernate: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/fr-FR/html/querysql.html